# Yii urlManager and jquery ajax GET request

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I am using [seourlmanager](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/seourlmanager/) class in urlmanager.
There is a field with ajax autocomplete that uses [Multicomplete Extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/multicomplete/).
The extension sends ajax request like 'controller/action?term=searchterm'.
The problem is that url  manager (seourlmanager) can't deal with the get query.
In url manager I have this rule:

```
'controller/action/<term:.*>'=>'controller/action'
```

How to adjust the url manager to work both with Multicomplete Extension and seourlmanager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the seourlmanager class to add query string in the end:

```
protected $_query;  
public function init() {  
  ..  
  $this -> _query = (!empty($urlParts['query'])) ? $urlParts['query'] : '';  
  ..  
}  
protected function _connectUrlParts() {
  $scheme = $this -> _scheme . '://';

  $port = (!empty($this -> _port)) ? ':' . $this -> _port : '';
  if($this->_query=='')
    return $scheme . $this -> _host . $port . $this -> _path;
  else
    return $scheme . $this -> _host . $port . $this -> _path.'?'.$this->_query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a generic rule in your config file something like this:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```

This would match the typical `controller/action` format with or without additional query parameters.

Since the autocomplete extension uses `?term=searchterm`, the `?term` doesn't need to be defined in the rule:

```
/controller/action?term=searchterm - CORRECT

/controller/action/term - INCORRECT
```

Comment: Do you have a .html suffix set (`'urlSuffix' => '.html'`)? If so, the url should use the suffix as well. Try to enter the url directly in your browser to see what combination gives you the correct response.